# How to implement a text mask in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text-mask

As described in the title, how to implement text mask in Flutter.

I am just writing a one below but not that suitable, since it can't display the mask to the user when typing, for example, when the text mask is 'MM/HH', if we do not display the slash during the user's typing, the user will typing the slash '/' themself, as they do not know the slash will auto-fill the input. There is a [example](https://text-mask.github.io/text-mask/) here that can explain what am I said (It's a web implementation, not Flutter), so how to implement the mask-like in this link in Flutter?

*This is my current implementation.*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MaskedTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final String mask;
  final String separator;

  MaskedTextInputFormatter({
    @required this.mask,
    @required this.separator,
  }) {
    assert(mask != null);
    assert(separator != null);
  }

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.text.length > 0) {
      if (newValue.text.length > oldValue.text.length) {
        if (newValue.text.length > mask.length) return oldValue;
        if (newValue.text.length < mask.length &&
            mask[newValue.text.length - 1] == separator) {
          return TextEditingValue(
            text:
                '${oldValue.text}$separator${newValue.text.substring(newValue.text.length - 1)}',
            selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
              offset: newValue.selection.end + 1,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

Any help are appreciated!

PS: I searched a Flutter package [mask_text_input_formatter](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/mask_text_input_formatter), seems it also can't display the mask when typing, see [issue](https://github.com/siqwin/mask_text_input_formatter/issues/44).

Answer (score 1):

try by adding extra condition for modifying text value

1. add 1 extra condition.

   ```html
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

   class MaskedTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
     final String mask;
     final String separator;

     MaskedTextInputFormatter({
       @required this.mask,
       @required this.separator,
     }) {
       assert(mask != null);
       assert(separator != null);
     }

     @override
     TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
         TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
       if (newValue.text.length > 0) {
         if (newValue.text.length > oldValue.text.length) {
           if (newValue.text.length > mask.length) return oldValue;
           if (newValue.text.length < mask.length &&
               mask[newValue.text.length - 1] == separator &&
               newValue.text.substring(newValue.text.length - 1) != separator) {
             return TextEditingValue(
               text:
                   '${oldValue.text}$separator${newValue.text.substring(newValue.text.length - 1)}',
               selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
                 offset: newValue.selection.end + 1,
               ),
             );
           }
         }
       }
       return newValue;
     }
   }
   ```
2. by using regex depending your need.

   ```
     FilteringTextInputFormatter(r"[A-za-z][A-Za-z]\/[A-za-z][A-Za-z]", allow: false);
   ```

OR

```
     FilteringTextInputFormatter(r"[A-za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\/[A-za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]", allow: false);
```

example as below
allow parameter is for if you want to allow particular pattern to be accepted or not

```
Textfield(
  label: "CardNumber",
  hint: "CardNumber",
  focusNode: cardNumberFocus,
  textInputFormatter: [
    MaskedTextInputFormatter(mask: 'xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx', separator: ' '),
    FilteringTextInputFormatter(r"[A-za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\/[A-za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]", allow: true);
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  But I am still do not understand what's the meaning of the `allow` param?  And what's the `FilteringTextInputFormatter`?

Comment: FilteringTextInputFormatter  is built in formatter for textfield , in that you have to pass allow parameter to true/false

Comment: Using your updated answer, I can't typing any character in the textfield, seems it will prevent all characters.

Comment: Hi kishan vekariya, could you pls help to do a minimal sample in https://dartpad.dev/?

Comment: https://codepen.io/kishan-sa/pen/YzZgZxx  you can see example here on codepen

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your answer, but this is not what am i want, what am i want is: once user typing, the separator should be display to guide user to entering. Just like `guide` parameter in https://text-mask.github.io/text-mask/.